# Collecting and grouping data - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I’m creating a module (PHP) that is allows the scheduling of ad images.

The following tables are used.

**Ad Space (ad_traffic_mgr_spaces)**
[image]

**Ad Images (ad_traffic_mgr_images)**
[image]

**Ads Manager (ad_traffic_mgr)**
[image]

The ad_traffic_mgr table is queried to collect data that would fit within a specific range. For example, all data where the timestamps land within the month of June, 2016.

The graphical display of the interface is shown in an HTML table, with each table representing one month. A block of rows, separated by a visual and textual indication so you know which ad space you are working on, then represents each ad space.

[image]

The top row is the interactive portion where, horizontally, each cell represents one day of the month. When a user clicks on the day, an editor opens allowing an image to be assigned, and the selection of a stop date, with the selected day as the start date.

Under the row of days is where we have the graphical representation of each image as it is scheduled. This is where my question for MySQL comes.

Ads can be assigned to display on within the same timeframe. When this happens the system then randomly selects one of these ad images. Obviously, ads that share any part of the same timeframe cannot exist on the same line.

What I want to know is, is there a way to tell MySQL to select the data for this ad space, for the entire month timeframe, then group the data where each row is in a chronographic order of the entire collection of data, like that of the image above?

Thanks in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: If you do not get an answer, maybe you should look at [dba stack](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The answer is *Most likely - Yes*.  However, showing pictures is not helpful. You need to show your table structure, sample data and what you expect as an output.

Comment: I edited the document. Hope it helps.